# How to make javascript countdown continue after refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to make javascript countdown continue after refreshing until the end even if page closed if possible without a database. I have done some searching but couldn't apply any on this code at all.

Can anyone help me with this one, please? I need to get it working without replacing the whole thing.

```js
let countdown;
const timerDisplay = document.querySelector('.display__time-left');
const endTime = document.querySelector('.display__end-time');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-time]');

function timer(seconds) {
  // clear any existing timers
  clearInterval(countdown);

  const now = Date.now();
  const then = now + seconds * 1000;
  displayTimeLeft(seconds);
  displayEndTime(then);
  
  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);
    // check if we should stop it!
    if(secondsLeft < 0) {
      document.getElementById('itimer').style.display = 'none'
      document.getElementById('ifree').innerHTML = "done!";
      document.getElementById("ifree").style.fontSize = "3.5rem";
       clearInterval(interval);
      clearInterval(countdown);
      return;
    }
    // display it
    displayTimeLeft(secondsLeft);
  }, 1000);
  document.getElementById('itimer').style.display = 'unset'
  document.getElementById("ifree").style.fontSize = "15px";
}

function displayTimeLeft(seconds){
 const minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
 const remainderSeconds = seconds % 60; 
 const display = `${minutes}:${remainderSeconds < 10 ? '0' : '' }${remainderSeconds}`;``
 document.title = display;
 timerDisplay.textContent = display;
}

function displayEndTime(timestamp){
 const end = new Date(timestamp);
 const hour = end.getHours();
 const minutes = end.getMinutes();
 endTime.textContent = `... ${hour}:${minutes}`;
}

function startTimer() {
  const seconds = parseInt(this.dataset.time);
  timer(seconds);
}

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', startTimer));
document.customForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  console.log(mins);
  timer(mins * 60);
  this.reset();
});
```

```css
    .body{
  direction: rtl;
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
  color: black;
}
#ifree{
  font-size: 15px;
  color:black;
}
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: black;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.display__time-left {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 12px;
  color:white;
  text-shadow:4px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  color: black;
}

.timer {
  display:flex;
  min-height: 35vh;
  flex-direction:column;
  direction: rtl;
}

.timer__controls {
  display: flex;
}

.timer__controls > * {
  flex:1;
}

.timer__controls form {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
}

.timer__controls input {
  flex:1;
  border:0;
  padding:2rem;
}

.timer__button {
  background:none;
  border:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:black;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-bottom:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding:1rem;
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
}
.timer__leave {
  border:0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color:black;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  border-bottom:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding:1rem;
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
}
.timer__button:hover,
.timer__button:focus {
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  outline:0;
}

.display {
  flex:1;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  max-height: 105px;
}

.display__end-time {
  font-size: 3vh;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi', sans-serif;
  margin: 12px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  timer__button {
     font-size: 1px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <body>
          <div class="timer">
    <div class="timer__controls">
      <button data-time="1800" class="timer__button">30</button>
      <button data-time="3600" class="timer__button">60</button>
      <button data-time="5400" class="timer__button">90</button>
      <button data-time="7200" class="timer__button">120</button>
      <button data-time="14400" class="timer__button">240</button>
      <button class="timer__leave" id="timer__leave">OFF</button>
      <button data-time="0" class="timer__button">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="display">
      <h1 class="display__time-left" id="itimer"></h1>
      <p class="display__end-time" id="ifree"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: you can use window.localStorage for this purpose.

Comment: check this [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/q1j3Lyw9/) bro

Comment: is this ok for you

Comment: please use jsfiddle so i can edit in your demo, but first try yourself

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/iN4sser/jLkyb3r0/

Comment: check [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yxtnv2fg/)

Comment: @Naseer is above changes helpful ?

Comment: @shajji thank you, thats what i wanted to do, can i make it display the countdown without clicking the button? and when i click again on the button the timer should reset

Comment: @Naseer u want to reset timer at x button or at 240, 120... button

Comment: @shajji now if you press X button and go back to 240 it will not start from 240

Comment: check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yxtnv2fg/1/)

Comment: @shajji Thank you, now it's working just like what i want

Comment: glad to see this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the timer function

```
function timer(seconds) {
  // clear any existing timers
  clearInterval(countdown);

  const now = Date.now();
  const then = now + seconds * 1000;
  displayTimeLeft(seconds);
  displayEndTime(then);

  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    const secondsLeft = Math.round((then - Date.now()) / 1000);
    // check if we should stop it!
    if(secondsLeft < 0) {
      document.getElementById('itimer').style.display = 'none'
      document.getElementById('ifree').innerHTML = "متاح الآن!";
      document.getElementById("ifree").style.fontSize = "3.5rem";
       clearInterval(interval);
      clearInterval(countdown);
      localStorage.removeItem("timeLeft")
      return;
    }
    // display it
    localStorage.timeLeft=secondsLeft;
    displayTimeLeft(secondsLeft);
  }, 1000);
  document.getElementById('itimer').style.display = 'unset'
  document.getElementById("ifree").style.fontSize = "15px";
}
```

then add the below condition.

```
if(localStorage.timeLeft){
timer(localStorage.timeLeft);
}
```

Comment: amazing! can you make it work for multiple timers at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use localStorage?

Add 3 additional functions:

```
function loadTimeLeft() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.timeLeft)
}

function persistTimeLeft(timeLeft) {
    localStorage.timeLeft = JSON.stringify(timeLeft)
}


function clearTimeLeft() {
    localStorage.removeItem("timeLeft")
}
```

Then just plug it in:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const seconds = loadTimeLeft()
  if (seconds) {
      timer(seconds)
  }
}


function timer(seconds) {
....
  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    if(secondsLeft < 0) {
        ....
        clearTimeLeft() //added at the end of if statement
        return
    }

    displayTimeLeft(secondsLeft)
    persistTimeLeft(secondsLeft) //added at the end of callback
  }, 1000)
...
```